# Laravel upgrade Issue (7.4 to 8.0)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have tried to update the Laravel version to 8.0 from 7.4. While giving "composer update" I'm facing the following error.

[image]

And my PHP version is 7.4.

Comment: Show the composer.json and paste the error message *here* in the question.  No images of code please

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need version 1.0.1 or higher of jwtauth as you can see on https://packagist.org/packages/tymon/jwt-auth#1.0.1 to have it support version 8 of Laravel.

Change your version requirement in `composer.json` to `^1.0.1`.